# VBA Code Scraper not placing data in right columns

Tags: excel, vba

The code works fine, but I need it to extract ONLY emails and URLs and place the email in `Sheet1` "Scraper" NEXT BLANK ROW

```
Emails =  Column A
Urls =  Column B
```

Currently it extracts anything text, emails or URL and places them in `column A` or `B`.

I only need Emails or URLs. I have been stuck on this for sometime and can't seem to work it out

Also I am not sure if my DELETE DUPLICATES is deleting duplicate rows or duplicates in column. It SHOULD be duplicate rows.

#### How the code works:

On `Sheet2` "URL List" I have a list of URLs, the code runs through this and places the results onto `Sheet1` "Scraper". and deletes any duplicates

It is only supposed to scraper email and URLs and place them in `Column A`,`B` on NEXT BLANK ROW.

I have tried to fix the problem but it is out of my scope.

```
Private Sub fbStart_Click()
'Set sheet2 URL List and open Internet Explorer
    Dim lr          As Long
    Dim x           As Long
    Dim arr()       As Variant
    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Dim ie          As Object
    Dim dd(1 To 2)  As String
    Dim Fr          As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Url List")
    With wks
        Fr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(1, 5).Value = lr
        arr = .Range(.Cells(Fr, 1), .Cells(lr, 1)).Value
    End With
        
    'Show Internet Explorer and add delay in seconds if needed
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:0")
        
        For x = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            .navigate arr(x, 1)
            wtime = Time
            Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
                DoEvents
                
            'Skip pages with Captchas  + write the word Captcha in Sheet 2 Column C
                If Time > (wtime + TimeValue("00:00:10")) Then
                    Cells(x + 1, "C").Value = "Captcha"
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            
            On Error Resume Next
            'Variable for document or data which need to be extracted out of webpage, change innertext number if same class used
            Dim doc As HTMLDocument
            Set doc = ie.document
            dd(1) = doc.getElementsByClassName("_50f4")(2).innerText
            dd(2) = doc.getElementsByClassName("_50f4")(3).innerText
            
           
            'Paste the web data into Sheet1 "Scraper" in next BLANK ROW
            With Sheet1
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 2).Value = dd
            End With
            
            ' Put A number 1 in Sheet2 "Url List"column B to notify this URL is done
            Sheets("Url List").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = 1
            
             'Deletes duplicates in column A Sheet1
            Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
            Columns(2).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
            
             'Count No1 in sheet2 Column B
            With Worksheets("Url List")
                Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                Sheets("Url List").Range("B1").Value = Lastrow
            End With
            Call Autoclick_Click
        Next x
       .Quit
    End With
    
    'Hide FaceBook Scraper Form
    ScraperForm.Hide
   
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a FaceBook Scraper, scrapes the "about " pages here is a link [link]https://www.facebook.com/pg/SalemFordNH/about/?ref=page_internal[link]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is to show you how to handle finding email and website address. You already have your loop and de-duplicate. Below are helper methods for extracting the required info. You can simply assign from the variables `email` and `website` to your cells in loop. I show a method using a helper function to determine lastRow in target sheet and writing out variables to correct columns in one go.

I can help with implementing the loop integration if needed, but the emphasis here was on explaining what could be done for identifying those elements of interest and how to write out to correct columns. Tbh - de-duplicating is so easily done in sheet at end but you can also use macro recorder to get perfectly functional code for that single step/use existing SO answers.

---

**tl;dr;**

This would be a lot easier if  `:contains` / `:has` css pseudo classes were permitted. Instead, my approach is as follows:

1. **email** - find the `href` attribute whose value starts with `mailto`

[image]

2. **website** - check that there is a website icon on the page

[image]

Specify a parent of both the website icon and the website address

[image]

Loop all matches to that parent specification checking if contains the website icon (this is where pseudo class selectors would have simplified things). If match found then we have the shared parent of both icon and hopefully website address; use `childOfSiblingCssSelector` (we are looking at a child of the following div in this case) css selector to extract the website url.

---

**Notes:**

1. The entire thing is kept quite high level/generic such that you can adjust your css selectors to hopefully cater for different scenarios. Consequence - may seem a little verbose.
2. Helper functions are provided to handle element matching. Name these in a way that makes sense for what they are doing. I think some room for improvement here.
3. Whilst technically the second helper, `GetText`, could be used to extract the email address (I'd probably add another argument to function call to specify attribute to extract) as well as website address, it seems far quicker, currently, to simply target the appropriate `href` as detailed above.
4. I have kept the css selectors as local variables close to their usage; you could have them as constants, closer to top of module, where easier to access perhaps? Unsure without seeing how this performs over time/different urls
5. Css selectors are chosen over `.getElementsBy` methods for two reasons: 1) there is browser optimization for css selectors so, if well formulated, css will be faster 2) I want to preserve the flexibility of the code/helper functions - you have far more specificity with css selectors in terms of what patterns you can express. I deemed this important as I don't know what future cases you may need to handle.
6. I am deliberately not using class name and index e.g. `doc.getElementsByClassName("_50f4")(2).innerText`, as I am unfamiliar with the range of potential use cases; this feels a little fragile as relies on consistent ordering and numbering of elements (at least up to these indices).

---

**TODO:**

1. Rather than instantiate a new `HTMLDocument` each time in `GetText`, it is more efficient to pass another  `HTMLDocument` argument in the function signature i.e. from calling procedure. A re-factor could take that into consideration.
2. This type of coding might lend itself to being class based in the future. Particularly if error handling is to be added and further functions.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References > HTML Object Library
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scraper")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.facebook.com/pg/SalemFordNH/about/?ref=page_internal%5Blink%5D"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            Dim email As String, website As String, iconCssSelector As String
            'iconCssSelector for website icon in this instance
            iconCssSelector = "[src='https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yV/r/EaDvTjOwxIV.png']"

            If ElementIsPresent(ie.document, "[href^=mailto]") Then
                email = ie.document.querySelector("[href^=mailto]").innerText
            Else
                email = "Not found"
            End If

            Dim parents As Object, sharedParentCssSelector As String, childOfSiblingCssSelector As String
            sharedParentCssSelector = "._5aj7" 'target parent of both icon and the website link
            childOfSiblingCssSelector = "._50f4" '< to target website address after finding right parent

            If ElementIsPresent(ie.document, iconCssSelector) _
                And ElementIsPresent(ie.document, sharedParentCssSelector) Then

                Set parents = ie.document.querySelectorAll(sharedParentCssSelector) 'css selector used to allow for greater flexibility in element matching
                website = GetText(ie.document, parents, iconCssSelector, childOfSiblingCssSelector)
            Else
                website = "Not found"
            End If
        End With
        'Assumes headers already present
        Dim nextRow As Long
        nextRow = GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1
        ws.Cells(nextRow, 1).Resize(1, 2) = Array(email, website)
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function ElementIsPresent(ByVal document As HTMLDocument, ByVal cssSelector As String) As Boolean
    ElementIsPresent = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector).length > 0
End Function

Public Function GetText(ByVal document As HTMLDocument, ByVal parents As Object, ByVal iconCssSelector As String, ByVal childOfSiblingCssSelector As String) As String
    'in this instance and with microsoft IE DOM you cannot select for parent of an element with pseudo class _
    of :has(>child); nor use :contains... instead pass expected parent selector, that houses _
    both the icon element for website and the website address itself, and loop all matches checking for website icon _
    if found use childOfSiblingCssSelector to extract
    Dim i As Long, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    For i = 0 To parents.length - 1
        html.body.innerHTML = parents.item(i).innerHTML
        If ElementIsPresent(html, iconCssSelector) Then
            GetText = html.querySelector(childOfSiblingCssSelector).innerText
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    GetText = "Not found"
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Project references (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

**Additional reading:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

---

### Edit:

Example of loop - assumes no empty rows in column A between urls.

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References > HTML Object Library
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As Object, ws As Worksheet, wsUrls As Worksheet, urls()
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scraper")
    Set wsUrls = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Url List")

    With wsUrls
        urls = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value)
    End With
    Dim results(), r As Long
    ReDim results(1 To UBound(urls), 1 To 2)

    With ie
        .Visible = True

        For r = LBound(urls) To UBound(urls)
            .Navigate2 urls(r)

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            With .document

                Dim email As String, website As String, iconCssSelector As String
                'iconCssSelector for website icon in this instance
                iconCssSelector = "[src='https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yV/r/EaDvTjOwxIV.png']"

                If ElementIsPresent(ie.document, "[href^=mailto]") Then
                    email = ie.document.querySelector("[href^=mailto]").innerText
                Else
                    email = "Not found"
                End If

                Dim parents As Object, sharedParentCssSelector As String, childOfSiblingCssSelector As String
                sharedParentCssSelector = "._5aj7" 'target parent of both icon and the website link
                childOfSiblingCssSelector = "._50f4" '< to target website address after finding right parent

                If ElementIsPresent(ie.document, iconCssSelector) _
        And ElementIsPresent(ie.document, sharedParentCssSelector) Then

                    Set parents = ie.document.querySelectorAll(sharedParentCssSelector) 'css selector used to allow for greater flexibility in element matching
                    website = GetText(ie.document, parents, iconCssSelector, childOfSiblingCssSelector)
                Else
                    website = "Not found"
                End If
            End With
            'Assumes headers already present
            Dim nextRow As Long
            results(r, 1) = email
            results(r, 2) = website
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    nextRow = GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1
    ws.Cells(nextRow, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End Sub

Public Function ElementIsPresent(ByVal document As HTMLDocument, ByVal cssSelector As String) As Boolean
    ElementIsPresent = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector).length > 0
End Function

Public Function GetText(ByVal document As HTMLDocument, ByVal parents As Object, ByVal iconCssSelector As String, ByVal childOfSiblingCssSelector As String) As String
    'in this instance and with microsoft IE DOM you cannot select for parent of an element with pseudo class _
    of :has(>child); nor use :contains... instead pass expected parent selector, that houses _
    both the icon element for website and the website address itself, and loop all matches checking for website icon _
    if found use childOfSiblingCssSelector to extract
    Dim i As Long, html As HTMLDocument
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    For i = 0 To parents.length - 1
        html.body.innerHTML = parents.item(i).innerHTML
        If ElementIsPresent(html, iconCssSelector) Then
            GetText = html.querySelector(childOfSiblingCssSelector).innerText
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    GetText = "Not found"
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This is absolutely awesome  and way out of my depth. I would never have got this far. I have been stuck on this for so long.

Thanks for all the explanations as they will be some very interesting reading. I see you have set it to only visit 1 url. My original code went through a  LIST which was on sheet2 “Url List”.

If you could just add this but for me, so it works via a list of URLs on sheet2 starting at column A row 2. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: We can go through it all if you have questions. I will update for loop now.

Comment: Loop added for you.

Comment: Any questions please do ask I am happy to go through stuff.

Comment: Just 1 thing, and it not just this code, put other I also have for scraping that work on a similar was, the results are only added to the spreed sheet after the IE closes. Is there a way to show the results as they are found and auto save at about 20 to 30 results. As in the past my other codes have crashed and I have lost all the work. if its too much to do, then don't bother as this codes is awesome and I will have to make do... THANKS for everything your a star.

Comment: lots of approaches for doing that. You could loop and use r mod 20, for example, to determine when to write out current results to sheet and workbook save. You woud then size the array to populate according to batch size.

Comment: I forgot to mention at the beginning that I am EXTREMELY LIMITED in VBA. I have just ordered VBA for dummies of eBay, I’m on that level. I’m not quite ready to take over the world yet, my evil plans will have to wait. I read code better than I write and I can get a rough idea. It took me weeks to put together my code via trial & error, it took you 5min to fix it. PLEASE use laminate terms when explain stuff as currently its all just a mixture of high science & wizardry to me.  What take you 5min takes me weeks to do. I'm out here with my begging bowl & greatly appreciate all help given.

Comment: QHarr -  Your last comment is just high science & wizardry to me, I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have hospital today. I will update for you tonight/tomorrow.

Comment: No rush, take your time, Wishing you all the best

Comment: Not forgotten you

Comment: I did forget. Sorry. Still need help with this?

Comment: If it too much work then don't bother, Its just that the results are pasted at the end, it would be better if they were done as soon  as they are found

Comment: I know this is one of my old threads and originally I stated that it did not matter if the result were shown after the code had finished processing the last url, as I did not want to bother the developer to much with my request. This has now become an issue and I need the result to show as they are found as I need it for another project. 

I have been trying for over a month now to fix it, but I cannot work it out as this level of code it is way out of my depth. The code itself works, it just need to show the result when they are found and NOT after it has finished processing each url.